# Prove whether or not the following inferences hold using a suitable semantic method

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

$\forall x,\;P(x)\to Q(x),\;\forall x,\;Q(x)\to R(x),\;\lnot R(a)\models\lnot P(a)$

I don't know how to use a truth table to prove it due to ∀ in formula。

Comment: It is not prop calculus, but FOL: thus, truth table method does not work.

Comment: You have only to assume that $Pa$ holds and see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a semantic proof you must show that there *can be **no*** interpretation which evaluate all the premises as true but the conclusion as false.

In propositional calculus, a truth table does this by explicitly listing all of the interpretations.  However, this is First Order Logic, with *too many interpretations to list*, so truth tables will not work.

You have to argue based on the meaning of the symbols:

- Suppose $\neg P(a)$ is valued as *false*, while the premises are all true. As  $\forall x.(P(x)\to Q(x))$ entails that $P(a)\to Q(a)$, this will be held true too. … *So on* …

Comment: So: First step is supposing the conclusion( ¬P(a)) is false. Then get P(a) is true. Then as ∀x.(P(x)→Q(x)) entails that P(a)→Q(a) is true. Then as ∀x.(Q(x)→R(x)) entails that Q(a)→R(a) is true. Then  ¬R(a) and R(a), we get invalid. So, the supposition is false and P(a) is true. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that is basically it.

Comment: thank you very much, and by the way, I want to know whether this is for '⊨' rather than '⊢'.

Comment: $\vDash$ is the symbol for semantic entailment, and this is a semantic proof.  It does, however, closely mirror a syntactic proof.